cors error in python-socketio and fastapi
I am working on a personal chat app using fastapi ,python socketio and React . I have mounted the socketio app on startup event of fastapi. Now there is this issue that when i try to connect socket there is some or the other cors error, such as that of duplicated origin, mixed content or access-control-allow-origin is null, or loclahost:3000 is not an accepted origin, or headers cannot be "". For the CorsMiddleware i have tried different entries in allow_origins such as passing in "", or particular ip with their ports but to no avail.Also for socket Asyncserver, when I keep the cors_allowed_origins as an empty list it seems to work as cors is disabled for the socket but I want to allow only specific addresses.I am quite stuck and have also referred to other posts and articles . Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks
Here is my code for fastapi startup event and socket server:
#app.py

@app.on_event("startup")
    async def init_resources() -> None:
        socketio_server = SocketIOServer().init(room_namespace=room_namespace)
        sio_app = socketio.ASGIApp(
            socketio_server=socketio_server, socketio_path="", other_asgi_app=app
        )
        app.mount("/socket.io", sio_app)

    return app

#socket_server.py


def init(self, room_namespace: RoomNamespace, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> socketio.AsyncServer:
        self.sio = socketio.AsyncServer(
            async_mode="asgi",
            cors_allowed_origins=[],
            logger=True,
            engineio_logger=True,
        )
        self.sio.register_namespace(room_namespace)
        return self.sio

React code for socket
const socket = io(import.meta.env.VITE_SOCKET_SERVER_URI, {
      // transports: ['Socket', 'polling', 'flashsocket'],
      auth: {
        token: tokens?.access
      },
      withCredentials: true
    });


